# counting html table rows with domDocument

Tags: php, domdocument

I am using domDocument to count rows in html table.  This is the code I have

```
if(isset($_POST['List']) && $_POST['List'] == true)
{
    $data = file_get_contents('File.php');
    $dom = new domDocument;
    @$dom->loadHTML($data);
    $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    $table = $dom->getElementById('Table');
    $rows = substr_count($table, "<tr>");

    for($x=0;$x<$rows;$x++)
    {

    }
}
```

Stepping through the code, $rows is null.
This is the contents of $table

```
tagName:"table"
schemaTypeInfo:null
nodeName:"table" 
nodeValue:"\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tCategoryAMA1A2ABBECCEC1C1EDDED1D1EW\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t"
nodeType:1
parentNode:"(object value omitted)"
childNodes:"(object value omitted)"
firstChild:"(object value omitted)"
lastChild:"(object value omitted)"
previousSibling:"(object value omitted)"
nextSibling:null
attributes:"(object value omitted)"
ownerDocument:"(object value omitted)"
namespaceURI:null
prefix:""
localName:"table"
baseURI:null
textContent:"\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tCategoryAMA1A2ABBECCEC1C1EDDED1D1EW\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t"
```

I have changed the code as follows

```
$url = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$doc = new domDocument();
@$doc->loadHTMLFile($url);
$table = $doc->getElementById('Table');
$rows = $table->getElementsByTagName('tr');
$count = count($rows);
```

I submitted the form with 2 rows in the table, but the count is 1.
This is the contents of $table

```
tagName:"table"
schemaTypeInfo:null
nodeName:"table" 
nodeValue: "\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tCategoryAMA1A2ABBECCEC1C1EDDED1D1EW\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\tDate\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t"
nodeType:1
parentNode:"(object value omitted)"
childNodes:"(object value omitted)"
firstChild:"(object value omitted)"
lastChild:"(object value omitted)"
previousSibling:"(object value omitted)"
nextSibling:null
attributes:"(object value omitted)"
ownerDocument:"(object value omitted)"
namespaceURI:null
prefix:""
localName:"table"
baseURI:null
textContent: "\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tCategoryAMA1A2ABBECCEC1C1EDDED1D1EW\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\tDate\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t"
```

Does loadHTMLFile have the same restriction as file_get_contents, only seeing the original html?

Answer (score 1):

After you have selected the table, you can get its rows using `getElementsByTagName`.

```
$rows = $table->getElementsByTagName('tr');
```

The result will be a `DOMNodeList` object that has a `length` property, which should be the count you're looking for.

```
echo $rows->length;
```

It looks like you're just using the row count to set up a for loop, which may not be necessary, because you can iterate the set of rows with foreach.

```
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    // do something with the row
}
```

Comment: One minor problem.  Initially the table has 1 row, with a  button which lets the user add a row using JavaScript when clicked.  I've added a 2nd row.  The length is returning 1, not 2.  It looks like php is not seeing the row added by JavaScript, otherwise the length would be 2 wouldn't it?  Or is there another logical explanation?

Comment: No, that's the right explanation. With `file_get_contents`, you're just going to get the original, unmodified version of the page that's saved on disk. If you want to get the page state after it's modified on the client side, you'll have to write some JavaScript to collect the info you need and send it back.

Comment: So JavaScript on the fly, so to speak.  Hold modified html table data in js variables and read them after submission.  Is that what u mean?

Comment: Sort of. I mean actually submit the modified table data with JS in an AJAX request. If you just have data in JS variables and then submit a form normally (without JS) none of those variables are going to be available on the server side.

Comment: What triggers the AJAX request, JS or PHP?  Used AJAX once, a long time ago.

Comment: JS. Basically you'd need to replace whatever is currently submitting the data with JavaScript.

Comment: How does JS know when (form submission) to trigger an AJAX request?

Comment: I assume the way you're currently doing it is just by clicking a submit button on an HTML form. You can add an event handler to the button to execute your AJAX post instead of doing the default form submit.

Comment: Should I replace the php error checking with js as well?

Comment: The only way I can think of getting an accurate count of table rows in php is by using JavaScript and passing the value via ajax.   Is there a better way?